# ant design background scroll overflow hidden not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, antd

i have use antd 4.6.1 in my react project, here i use antd modal, drawer, select, drop down and more here if i open any one of mentioned things, like now i open modal, modal is opened, modal scroll is working, with the modal scroll, body scroll also working just like that all kind of element reacting, by default if any of modal, drawer or select opened, in body overflow hidden property not added that's why it's happening, i don't know why it's occurred,

i have search lot, https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21539 here they said to need to add overflow hidden property manually when those all open and remove it when those closed using normal javascript code, this is actually not a best solution for this situation,

so kindly assist me, how do i resolve this issue, Hope here i can get better solution

Helping hands are appreciable,